# Broken NAS with 2 1 TB SATA drives

Tags: data-recovery, raid

I am trying to recover data from a NAS that fell off a the top of a PC tower.  One drive "sounds" OK the other one probably has something physically wrong with it.

For the first drive I get the following when I try to mount it.

```
david@Office-ThinkPad-T520:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.
david@Office-ThinkPad-T520:~$
```

How do I read the data from it?  ANy help would be greatly appreciated since about 15years of photos have been backed up to the NAS. (I know I should have had a cloud backup to - but such is the benefit of hindsight :-(

The second drive makes clicking sounds. But I get this from `sudo fdisk - l` though after 15 minutes it didn't complete.

```
david@Office-ThinkPad-T520:~$ sudo fdisk -l
# /dev/loop0 - /dev/loop7 omitted

Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0005a44a

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 476053503 476051456  227G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       476055550 488396799  12341250  5,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       476055552 488396799  12341248  5,9G  b W95 FAT32

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

# /dev/loop8 - /dev/loop18 are omitted
```

Thanks Norbert
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb gives me

david@Office-ThinkPad-T520:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
[sudo] password for david: 
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EC723D09-7A4A-4F7F-A67D-CA77820D6E9D

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     65536   42008576   41943041    20G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2  42010624 1953523711 1911513088 911,5G Microsoft basic data
david@Office-ThinkPad-T520:~$

Comment: I removed output about /dev/loops as irrelevant. Please add output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` to the question.

Comment: This looks like `sdb2` is a raid member. Look at `/proc/mdstat` to find the md devices and try to mount them ( e.g. `/dev/md0`). It would also help if you add the output of  `cat /proc/mdstat` to your question.

Comment: david@Office-ThinkPad-T520:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>